# PostgreSQL 15 + Python 3.10+ plpython3u: 'psql: server closed the connection unexepectedly.' + 'The application has lost the database connection.'

Tags: python, windows, postgresql-15

I am trying to run a python script within a trigger in mi PostgreSQL 15 database in Windows 10.

I've already tried the solution proposed in the following link
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67852675/postgresql-13-python-3-7-9-plpython3u-psql-server-closed-the-connection-u#:~:text=ERROR%3A%20server%20closed%20the%20connection,or%20while%20processing%20the%20request.&text=The%20application%20has%20lost%20the%20database%20connection.,-(which%20is%20a&text=1-,and%20copy%20%22python37.,that%20you%20have%20admin%20rights.

I am still stucked in STEP 5. Every time I try to create the function I got the error message.

I've checked the installation notes and in theory it needs Python 3.9

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tzMaZ.png)

However, for some reason it looks like I need to copy in System 32 the file: **python310.dll** because any other version wouldn't accept this instruction:

```
CREATE EXTENSION plpython3u;
```

In any case, I've downloaded and tried with all these Python 10 versions and it doesn't work.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XmPjS.png)

Does anybody know how to by pass the situation?

Thanks in advance.

I've tried to follow several links. The one it got me furthest was:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67852675/postgresql-13-python-3-7-9-plpython3u-psql-server-closed-the-connection-u#:~:text=ERROR%3A%20server%20closed%20the%20connection,or%20while%20processing%20the%20request.&text=The%20application%20has%20lost%20the%20database%20connection.,-(which%20is%20a&text=1-,and%20copy%20%22python37.,that%20you%20have%20admin%20rights.

Answer (score 1):

I had exactly the same issue, but found a solution. You should install python 3.10.0, for all users (important), be sure to have python and python/Scripts in the path (before PG bin path), restart PG service and it should be ok.